# How to get PID's Memory, CPU usage using java program?

Tags: java, memory, cpu

I am trying to get the PID's Memory and CPU usage by a Java program.

I can be able to get PID of current program by the following code:

```
private static int getProcessId()
{

String name = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName();

StringBuffer pid = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0, l = name.length(); i < l; i++) {
    if (Character.isDigit(name.charAt(i))) {
        pid.append(name.charAt(i));
    } else if (pid.length() > 0) {
        break;
    }
    }
    try {
    return Integer.parseInt(pid.toString());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    return 0;
    }

}
```

By using the PID I want to calculate the Memory and CPU usage. Is there any methods to get those things?

For example suppose if I get PID as 2256 from the method `getProcessId()`. I want to calculate memory and CPU for the PID: 2256.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running on a Linux (or other UNIXy) system (probably, if you're talking about PIDs), there's a whole swag of stuff made available under the [`procfs` file system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs), assuming it's available to you.

You can nose around in `/proc/self` for the current process, or `/proc/<PID>` for another process.

For memory and CPU usage, I'd start with the `statm`, `status` and `stat`. See [here](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html) for a more detailed description.

Answer (score 0):

The information you want to display is platform specific. /proc (procfs) is standard mechanism in modern UNIXes. The [jproc](http://www.petertribble.co.uk/Solaris/jproc.html) is JNI to proc file system. You may find it very useful.

[From Author's blog](http://ptribble.blogspot.com/2009/08/jproc-procfs-from-java.html)  :

> As if accessing kstats from Java
>   wasn't enough, I've recently been
>   playing with accessing process
>   information - specifically the /proc
>   filesystem on Solaris - from java.
>   Thus was born JProc.
>
> The idea, eventually, is to link this
>   with JKstat and SolView to give a more
>   complete view of what's happening on a
>   Solaris system.